# need woodcutting recursion advice

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

You are given a log of wood of length 'n’. There are 'm’ markings on the log. The log must be cut at each of the marking. The cost of cutting is equal to the length of the log that is being cut. Given such a log, determine the least cost of cutting.

My partial solution is using recursion:
I am able to get the cost when i am going in sequence in the marking array i.e. from 0th cut to end of array cut. However i am stuck as to how to write code for the sequence when we are cutting not in sequence i.e. in random sequence such as the code can account for the cases when the cut is not in sequence and take a maximum for all of that cases.

One solution is to do all the permutation of the markings array. Call woodcut function for all the permutations and take maximum but that seems to be naive approach.

Any suggestions?

marking = [2, 4] (cut points)

```
int woodcut(length, cut_point, index){
    if (cut_point > length)
            return INFINITY
    first_half = cut_point;
    second_half = length - cut_point
    if (markings[index++] == exist) {
            if (next_cut_point > first)
                    cost = length + woodcut(second_half, next_cut_point-first)
            else    
                    cost = length + woodcut(first_half, next_cut_point)  
    } else if (index >= sizeof(markings))
            return cost;
}
```

http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5188262471663616

After looking up the answers and with some help from some generous folks, I was able to code up below solution:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int min(int a, int b)
    {
            return a>b?b:a;
    }

    int min_cut(int first, int last, int size, int *cuts)
    {
            int i;
            unsigned int min_cost = 1U<<30;
            /* there are no cuts */
            if (size == 2)
                    return 0;
            /* there is only one cut between the end points */
            if (size == 3)
                    return last - first;
            /* cut at all the positions and take minimum of all */
            for (i=1;i<size;i++) {
                    if (cuts[i] > first && cuts[i] < last) {
                            int cost = last-first + min_cut(first, cuts[i], i+1, cuts) +
                                                    min_cut(cuts[i], last, size - i, cuts);
                            min_cost = min(cost, min_cost);
                    }
            }
            return min_cost;
    }

    int main()
    {
            int cuts[] = {0, 2, 4, 7, 10};
            int size = sizeof(cuts)/sizeof(cuts[0]);
            printf("%d", min_cut(cuts[0], cuts[size-1], size, cuts));
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your question could use formatting. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You should state the source of the problem, and provide a link if possible.

Comment: @DouglasZare: there is no source. I got it from career cup site where it is asked by someone who attended google interview.

Comment: That is a source. You should include that in the statement of the question and link to the Career Cup site where it is discussed.

Comment: Again, you can edit the question to include that. This has at least two benefits. First, it lets people who are interested see the solutions proposed by others on that thread, to avoid a duplication of effort. Second, proper attribution means you are not trying to claim credit for inventing the problem.

Comment: In addition, many people have been posting problems from current programming competitions. By posting a different source, you encourage people who can answer but who don't want to help someone trying to cheat on a competition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach A:

First write a naive recursive function that calculates the cheapest cost of cutting into pieces from the `i`th mark to the `j`th mark.  Do that by taking the minimum over all possible first cuts of the cost of that first cut plus the minimum cost of cutting up the two side pieces.

Memoize this function so it is efficient.

Approach B:
Calculate a table of values for calculating the cheapest cost of cutting into pieces from the `i`th mark to the `j`th mark.  Do it with an outer loop of the number of marks `i` and `j` are separate, then with an inner loop of `i` and then a very inner loop of possible places to do the first cut.

Both methods work.  Both will be `O(m*m*m)`  I usually would go with approach A.

Comment: mind giving some code snippet for 'A' approach? Or providing more explanation for "the minimum over all possible first cuts of the cost of that first cut plus the minimum cost of cutting up the two side pieces"

Comment: something like this: if the length of the wood is '10' and cut point is [4, 6] 
if the cut point is '6' then 
min_cost[0, 10] = 10 + min(min_cost[0, 6], min_cost[6, 10])
min_cost[0, 6] = 6 + min(min_cost[0, 6], min_cost[6, 10])

Comment: @newbie_old My assumption when I see something like this is that the person is looking for help on a programming competition or homework.  Therefore I limit how much help I will give.

Comment: if you had seen my latest edits to the question you would not arrived at that conclusion, anyway I am writing the code now and will post it once it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic programming. Complexity O(m^3). Solution in python. Input is ordered list of marking positions, with the last item as the length of the log:

```
def log_cut(m):
  def _log_cut(a, b):
    if mat[a][b]==None:
      s=0
      min_v=None
      for i in range(a+1, b):
         v=_log_cut(a, i)+_log_cut(i, b)
         if min_v==None or v<min_v:
           min_v=v
      if min_v!=None:
        s=min_v+m[b-1]
        if a>0:
          s-=m[a-1]
      mat[a][b]=s
    return mat[a][b]

  mat=[[None for i in range(len(m)+1)] for j in range(len(m)+1)]
  s=_log_cut(0, len(m))
  return s
```

Answer (score -2):

This scenario is analogous to divide-and-conquer sorting.  Take quicksort, for example:

- There is a partition step that requires a linear pass over an array to divide it into two subarrays.  Similarly, the cost of cutting a log is equal to its length.
- There is then a recursive step in which each subarray is recursively sorted.  Similarly, you must recursively continue to cut each of the two pieces into which a log is cut, until you have cut at all marks.

Quicksort is, of course, O(n log n) in the best case, which occurs when each partition step (except base cases) divides the array into two nearly-equally-sized subarrays.  Thus, all you need to do is to find the mark closest to the middle, "cut" the log there, and recurse.

Comment: This heuristic does not produce the optimal cut in many examples. Suppose in a log of length 200, the marks are at 1, 99, 100, 101, and 199. You can cut the log in half, after which you have no real choices, and you get a total cost of 200 + 100 + 100 + 99 + 99 = 598. If you instead cut at 99, 101, 1, 199, 100, then the total cost is 200 + 101 + 99 + 99 + 2 = 501.